# URLSession parameters must be valid

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

This is the **Url** I am requesting for :

> https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.theverge.com%2Frss%2Findex.xml&api_key=u3vl3sxdva2cch7jjyrnynvwlhjycjrizhcsgmmq

If you run this on browser, it works fine and gives a JSON response. However I get this error in the catch block on running the following code : **URLSession parameters must be valid**  :

```
let callURL = URL.init(string: urlString)    // urlString is the above url
var request = URLRequest.init(url: callURL!)
request.addValue(ContentType_ApplicationJson, forHTTPHeaderField: HTTPHeaderField_ContentType)
request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod_Get    
let dataTask = urlSession.dataTask(with: request) { (data,response,error) in
        if error != nil{
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        do {
            if let resultJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary{
                print("Result",resultJson)
                if let news = resultJson.value(forKeyPath: "articles") as? [NSDictionary]{
                    print("News",news)
                    completion(news)
                    return
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error -> \(error)")
        }
    }

dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: replace your `request.addValue` line with this: `request.addValue("Content-Type", forHTTPHeaderField: "application/json")` and the `request.httpMethod` with `request.httpMethod = "GET"`, that should do the trick.

Comment: Though it is not my place to comment on down vote, but I don't see any problem with this question. I am aware it is not in my rights to object for a down vote but one should wisely use their privileges. This I have realised only after gaining a good reputation with time. Rightly said - With great power comes great responsibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what is wrong in your code but I have tested your above code in playground I am getting news below is the code

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let urlString = "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.theverge.com%2Frss%2Findex.xml&api_key=u3vl3sxdva2cch7jjyrnynvwlhjycjrizhcsgmmq"
let callURL = URL.init(string: urlString)    // urlString is the above url
var request = URLRequest.init(url: callURL!)
request.addValue("Content-Type", forHTTPHeaderField: "application/json")
request.httpMethod = "GET"
let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data,response,error) in

    let res = response as! HTTPURLResponse
    print(res)
    if error != nil{
        print(error!)
        return
    }
    do {
        if let resultJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary{
            print("Result",resultJson)
            if let news = resultJson.value(forKeyPath: "articles") as? [NSDictionary]{
                print("News",news)

                return
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error -> \(error)")
    }
}

dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: I hardcoded urlString , HTTP Header Fields and HTTP Method.

Comment: Yes I think check your header constants value.

Comment: Though all three answers are correct, awarding this one because this was the first.

Answer (score 1):

This worked with me

```
    let callURL = URL.init(string: "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.theverge.com%2Frss%2Findex.xml&api_key=u3vl3sxdva2cch7jjyrnynvwlhjycjrizhcsgmmq")    // urlString is the above url
    var request = URLRequest.init(url: callURL!)
     request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.get.rawValue
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data,response,error) in
        if error != nil{

           print(error)
        }
        do {
            if let resultJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary{
                print("Result",resultJson)
                if let news = resultJson.value(forKeyPath: "articles") as? [NSDictionary]{
                    print("News",news)

                    return
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error -> \(error)")
        }
    }

    dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: I see that headers is the only thing different. Never thought that so.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an URLRequest for a GET request, it's the default, just pass the `URL`

This works, however there is no value for key `articles`

```
let urlString = "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.theverge.com%2Frss%2Findex.xml&api_key=u3vl3sxdva2cch7jjyrnynvwlhjycjrizhcsgmmq"
let callURL = URL(string: urlString)!
let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: callURL) { (data,response,error) in
    if error != nil { return }
    do {
        if let resultJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:Any] {
            print("Result",resultJson)
//            if let news = resultJson["articles"] as? [[String:Any]] {
//                print("News",news.count)
//                return
//            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error -> \(error)")
    }
}
dataTask.resume()
```

And – as always – **do not use `NSDictionary` and `valueForKey` in Swift** and `.allowFragments` is pointless if the root object is a collection type.

Comment: You are right on the article part. And on the GET request as well.

Comment: One query though. If header won't be specified, then how would request come to know that response should be in json or xml ? I have had this idea all along since the start.

Comment: If there is a parameter to specify the output it's passed in the URL. In this case `rss2json` and `api.json` implies that the output is JSON

Comment: Right. So these params hold true for generic url's where format is not specified.